# how to use push button as image field in itext 5

Tags: javascript, java, itext

can anyone please help me with the java code to use push button as an image field using itext 5. I have tried the below code but does not work

```
com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PushbuttonField button = new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PushbuttonField(writer, new com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle(90, 500, 140, 800), "submit");
button.setText("POST");
button.setBackgroundColor(new com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor(255, 255, 255));
button.setVisibility(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PushbuttonField.VISIBLE_BUT_DOES_NOT_PRINT);
com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfFormField submit = button.getField();
submit.setAction(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAction.createSubmitForm("/book/fdf", null, 0));
writer.addAnnotation(submit);

com.itextpdf.text.pdf.TextField file = new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.TextField(writer, new com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle(90, 500, 140, 800), "image");
file.setOptions(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PushbuttonField.FILE_SELECTION);
com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfFormField upload = file.getTextField();
upload.setAdditionalActions(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName.U, com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAction.javaScript("this.getField('image').browseForFileToSubmit();"+ "this.getField('submit').setFocus();", writer));
writer.addAnnotation(upload);
```

Comment: The actual PDF form technology, AcroForm forms, does not offer an image field type. For some contexts an usable work-around is to use a push button the appearance of which is changed to embed the image. Would this be ok for you?

Comment: Yes this would help me a lot. I read about this but not able to understand how exactly to implement it. Can you please help me with the code for implementing this - @mkl

Comment: Considering your edit you appear to want to post the PDF form as fdf. This is a bit critical as the image is not the *value* of the push button but merely its *appearance*, so it is **not** transmitted as part of a simple fdf post. If you set the **IncludeAppendSaves** submit-form action flag, any added image will be included in the incremental updates.

Comment: By the way, it wasn't clear from the start that you wanted to post the form from a PDF viewer. The answer I had in mind would have shown how to replace the image of a pushbutton field using iText and probably how to extract it using itext.

Comment: Yes i want to post the form from pdf viewer

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
<label for="pre">
   Your Image
</label>
<a id="pre" onclick="$('#imagetr').trigger('click'); ">
   <img id="preview" class="col img img-fluid" src="images/defaultloadimage.jpg"  title="your default place holder" />
 </a>
 <input type="file" name="image" id="imagetr" style="display:none;" />
```

```
<script>
     function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#imagetr").change(function () {
        readURL(this);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Javad. I am new to iText and i am generating the PDF document using iText java code. I am using PdfFormFields  to add textbox and checkbox fields. Is there any method to add an image field as form field?